# Seats - Principles for comfort

Tags: sculpting

I am considering using algorithmic design to design seats. However, I also want the result to be something people would actually want to use. So, I have to ensure that the result is comfortable.

Besides copying and looking at seats I find comfortable, are there any resources I can use to find design principles for comfortable seating?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be related to traditional hand-made arts and crafts.

Comment: If there are, the people who made my couch sure didn't have access to them.

Comment: Hm. I am wavering here. The principles of human comfort can be defined (I distinctly remember some from when I was studying architecture, e.g. the formula for stairs or good heights for stools), drawing has them (golden ratio etc. for aesthetically pleasing design), sewing and others as well... And I would possibly see such a chair as a “sculpture”, “hand made” by an algorithm as artistic process, not an industrial product.

Comment: @AllisonC Well, the fact that I intend to use algorithms is irrelevant to the question itself, so I can edit that paragraph. I, probably unnecessarily, wanted to contextualize the question. Any resource that can teach comfort is relevant to anybody who wants to create furniture, regardless of the tools used.

Comment: I retract my close vote. If we had someone asking for standards or algorithms to design comfortable garments or to create arbitrary Origami figures, we would probably consider it on topic, too. This seems to be no different, even if furniture making is not considered as "hand craft" anymore.

Comment: This is the study of ergonomics, essentially; I'm also on the fence about how topical it is. Honestly, I think you are more likely to get the algorithm or analytical resources you seek from an engineering site, not this one... Would you perhaps be interested in migration?

Comment: @Erica Yes, this is essentially a question regarding an application of ergonomics. However, I don't think the engineering SE's are more appropriate than this one; Those do not deal with design. The only SE sites that would be more appropriate are Ergonomics SE, IxD SE and the like, but those do not exist. So, if I cannot ask design questions here either, no relevant SE exists.

Comment: As a former industrial engineer, ergonomics is definitely a subspecialty of engineering, but you can leave it here if you prefer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> are there any resources I can use to find design principles for comfortable seating?

Here are a few to get started:

[Must-Have Measurements for Comfortable Seating](https://www.woodmagazine.com/must-have-measurements-for-comfortable-seating)
[image]

With a little work the drawing above can be turned into an algorithm.
The key variable will be the dimensions of the person sitting in the chair.

Another useful drawing:
[image]
I [found the picture here](https://muhammadzainudinnazha.wordpress.com/category/furniture-design-workshop/) but I don't think this is the original source.

[From Concept to Comfort: Build a Casual Chair](https://www.canadianwoodworking.com/plans-projects/concept-comfort-build-casual-chair)
Good article describing the process from ideation to finished product.

Summarizing:
 1. Ideation
 2. Sketches
 3. Prototyping
 4. Testing
 5. Adjusting (iterate steps 3, 4, and 5 until happy)
 6. Build final version

The steps are not unique to chair creation. This process should allow you to build experience, gather data, and derive the information you seek.

Other resources:
[Standard Dimensions for Furniture Design](http://www.cawspi.org/Furniture%20Design.pdf)

Comment: Darnn, I did not know you needed a computer . I built a 20 ft long bench on my deck 22 years ago that has been very comfortable ( although a seat cushion is good for sitting a long time).  Seat is 10 degrees and back is 105 degrees ( 15 degrees past vertical .